# Validating an Email Address using RegularExpression

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wrote this regex function

```
    Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal txtEmailAddress As String) As Boolean

    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$"
    If Regex.IsMatch(txtEmailAddress, pattern) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

And on-calling the function in a sub procedure:

```
  If ValidateEmailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text) = True Then
    Else
       MessageBox.Show("Email Not Valid")
    End If
    Sub Procedure
```

When i enter the email, correctly or incorrectly i get the same message i.e email not valid,in addition to that on stepping through the code after the If statement it ignores the return true. Please can anyone spot what the issue is here?

Comment: the answer i got for this particular question few days ago didnt work therefore shouldnt be accepted right.

Comment: But you have 15 questions you have asked and only two of them have been marked as accepted answers. You need to review the answers given and mark accepted as appropriate - If you have found your own solution post that and mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: I think your `ValidateEmailAddress` method should just read `Return txtEmailAddress.Contains("@")`...

Comment: @BigYellowCactus in that case how would it verify if the email is valid since i would just be returning the email?

Comment: @Jide No, you would just return if the email contains a `@`. Everything else is wasted time/efford IMHO. Your regular expression would fail anyway to validate an email address. [Here] is a regular expression that checks an email address according to the RFC 822 grammar. If someone does not want to enter his email address, he can just enter something like `dflshf@sdjflkfhs.net`. This is a valid address, and you have no way to validate if this is a *real* address. The same is true in the case someone just enters the wrong email address by accident. So why bother with it anyway?

Comment: Great idea i didnt think of it this way it works now actually,thanks alot, theres the function below:  
        If txtEmailAddress.Contains("@") Then
            Return True
        Else
            MsgBox("Email address is not valid")
        End If

Comment: @Jide I posted my comment as an answer, so maybe some else can also benefit from it.

Comment: Your code makes a few things more complex than need be: you write `If something Then Return True Else Return False End If` … all that can (and should!) be written as `Return something`. Similarly, *don’t write* `If x = True Then` …, just write `If x Then`. And finally, don’t write `If x Then { nothing here } Else something End If` … write `If Not x Then something End If`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to BigYellowCactus's answer :- You can use something like this - I think this is preferable to using regex:

```
Public Shared Function IsValidEmailAddress(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim address As New MailAddress(emailAddress)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

This will return `False` with `@abc.com` and `bill@` whereas just checking for `@` will return `True`

Comment: one pointer would be that methods in modules cannot be declared Shared. whats the point using regex when you can just write a simple fuction like this. thanks alot it works perfectly!

Comment: +1 for this solution. But it still fails the main problem, and also does not work correct according to the RFC 5322 standard. As an example, this code fails to reject the totally invalid email address `this_is_invalid....@example.com`.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - agreed, this will not do the same checking as the regex but preferable to a page of regex code IMO.

Comment: on testing the code i realized it only checks for the @, i tried "noname@abc.com" and also "--fasholajide@gmail.com.net/gmail"  it returned true. therefore only checking for the @ which is the same as the code provided by @BigYellowCactus.

Comment: It does some more checks and it is totally legit, but it is not perfect. What I am trying to say is that you should not care too much. It is just not worth it.

Comment: I had to deal with this a couple weeks ago and from poking around I basically found that the ONLY sure fire way to validate an e-mail is to try sending something to it but this brings up the issue that if it works then you just sent your customer a bogus e-mail and might cause them to forward your stuff to junk mail. So, in my case at least, I chose to check very basic things that are quick and easy and call it a day. The checks I chose were that it contains an @ followed by anthing then a "." folowed by any number of characters and that it didn't start with a number.